# C# interface specfying a generic return type

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I have something like:

```
public interface IExample
{
  int GetInteger()
  T GetAnything(); //How do I define a function with a generic return type???
^^^^^
}
```

Is this possible???

Answer (score 62, accepted):

If the whole interface should be generic:

```
public interface IExample<T>
{
  int GetInteger();
  T GetAnything();
}
```

If only the method needs to be generic:

```
public interface IExample
{
  int GetInteger();
  T GetAnything<T>();
}
```

Comment: +1. I totally forgot that method can have its own type parameter :)

Comment: If using .NET 4.0 better to use covariance if possible: public interface IExample<out T>, T GetAnything<out T>();

Comment: how do I implement the interface function then?

Comment: Note that if the interface as a whole is generic, a class implementing it may either be a generic class with that same type parameter, or will have to explicitly implement the interface for whatever types it is supposed to support.  In the former case, to have `GetAnything` return type `Foo`, one must have a `ClassImplementingIExample<Foo>`.

Answer (score 6):

```
public interface IExample<T>
{
   int GetInteger()
   T GetAnything();
}
```

Tadaa :) !

Or alternatively, you can just return System.Object and cast it to whatever you want.

Comment: This is pretty ugly - `return System.Object and cast it to whatever you want.`

Comment: Don't think this is what he is asking

Answer (score 3):

If you dont want the entire interface(IExample) to be generic, then you can do this too

```
public interface IExample
{
  int GetInteger();
  T GetAnything<T>();     
}
```

Comment: just to clarify, if you declare the method this way in an interface, when you implement it on the class that implements the interface, you will have to keep it as a generic method and you will only be able to specify its type when you call the method on the object instantiated from the class that implements the interface, not in the class itself